# How to not save into database if document upload is failed

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-rest-framework

When a user uploads a document and clicks submit the file is stored in a folder and a database entry is created along with bunch of other details. What I am looking for is to avoid the save if the document doesn't get uploaded into the specific location.

serializer.py

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ['file', 'doc_type']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        msg = self.__construct_message_body()
        validated_data['type'] = Request.request_types[-1][0]
        validated_data['input_message'] = msg
        instance = ParseRequest.objects.create(**validated_data)
        msg['request_id'] = instance.id
        instance.input_message = msg
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class DocumentView(CreateAPIView, ResponseViewMixin):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser,)
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            data = request.data
            serializer = self.get_serializer(
                data=data, context={'request': request})
            serializer.is_valid()
            serializer.save()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            return self.error_response(message=ERROR_RESPONSE['UPLOAD_DOCUMENT'])
        return self.success_response(message=SUCCESS_RESPONSE['UPLOAD_DOCUMENT'])
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting or what is the problem you are facing by the code? Explain

Comment: Not facing any error, I joust want to avoid the save into db if file upload fails. don't know how to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [atomic transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly). And you can change your code as follows:

`views.py`

```py
from django.db import transaction

class DocumentView(CreateAPIView, ResponseViewMixin):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser,)
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                data = request.data
                serializer = self.get_serializer(
                    data=data, context={'request': request})
                serializer.is_valid()
                serializer.save()
                return self.success_response(message=SUCCESS_RESPONSE['UPLOAD_DOCUMENT'])
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            return self.error_response(message=ERROR_RESPONSE['UPLOAD_DOCUMENT'])
```

If some error occurs inside the `with` block, it will not be saved into the database.